# Database items getting deleted when referencing them multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a simple blogging application to get .NET MVC 4 down and I am having a problem. Everything works except for when I try to tag a blog using an array of strings for each blog like so:

```
 public class BlogEntry
    {
        public List<Comment> BlogComments { get; set; }
        public virtual List<String> RawTags { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Tag> BlogTags { get; set; }
        public virtual User Author { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public bool IsAcceptingComments { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastEdited { get; set; }

    }

 public class Tag
    {
         [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int RefCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Upon creating a blog and tagging it, I save tags into the BlogEntry model using this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public int Create(string data)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                BlogEntry newBlog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlogEntry>(data);

                newBlog.Author = Session["user"] as User;
                newBlog.AuthorId = newBlog.Author.Id;
                newBlog.IsVisible = true;
                newBlog.IsAcceptingComments = true;
                newBlog.LastEdited = DateTime.Now;
                newBlog.DatePosted = DateTime.Now;
                newBlog.BlogTags = new List<Tag>();

                foreach (String s in newBlog.RawTags)
                {
                    // First check to see if the tag already exists
                    Tag check = Db.Tags.Where(m => m.Name == s).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (check != null)
                    {
                        check.RefCount++;
                        newBlog.BlogTags.Add(check);
                        Db.Tags.Attach(check);
                        Db.Entry(check).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        Db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Create a new tag
                        Tag newTag = new Tag();
                        newTag.Name = s;
                        newTag.RefCount = 1;
                        newBlog.BlogTags.Add(newTag);
                        Db.Tags.Add(newTag);
                    }
                }

                Db.BlogEntries.Add(newBlog);
                Db.SaveChanges();

                return newBlog.Id;
            }

            return -1;
        }
```

First I do a check to see if a tag already exists.. If it does, I try to add the same tag, `check` to the newBlog object. I would have thought that this would just save a reference to this Tag object in the DbSet, however, if I create multiple blogs posts with the tag "html" and then run a query to see what blogs have the html tag, only the most recently tagged blog retains this value.... What can I do so that I can have multiple BlogEntry objects with the same Tag object in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my dev machine in front of me right now, so this is just a guess, but I figure it's better than making you wait until tomorrow...

I don't think you need the last 3 lines in your `if(check!=null)` and in fact, I wonder if they aren't messing you up:

```
Db.Tags.Attach(check);
Db.Entry(check).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
Db.SaveChanges();
```

You shouldn't need to attach because you got it from the Db object already, so it should already be being tracked.  This means you don't need to change the state and as for the SaveChanges, you are going to do that below.

And now another disclaimer: I've done some work with Entity Framework (version 6, if you want to know), but not with MVC, so it may be different, but my understanding is that it is better to create a new DbContext for each set of instructions, rather than having a class variable that just tracks running changes.  I'm not sure if that is what you are doing or not, but it sort of looks that way from this code sample. Assuming that is relevant in MVC, you may consider creating a new DbContext (Db) at the top of your create method.

Let me know how it goes--if this doesn't help, I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to update the `Tag` class so that it can track its registered blog entries itself. Here the `BlogEntry` and `Tag` classes have a `many-to-many` relationship. So the `Tag` class would look like below:

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RefCount { get; set; }
    public virtual List<BlogEntry> BlogEntries { get; set; } // MODIFICATION
}
```

Now you have to add the blog entry to all of its tags for back referencing to meet your query in an easy way. Look for the modifications I have made in the `for-loop` below:

```
foreach (String s in newBlog.RawTags)
{ 
    // First check to see if the tag already exists
    Tag check = Db.Tags.Where(m => m.Name == s).FirstOrDefault();
    if (check != null)
    {
        check.RefCount++;
        check.BlogEntries.Add(newBlog); // MODIFICATION
        newBlog.BlogTags.Add(check);
        Db.Tags.Attach(check);
        Db.Entry(check).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a new tag
        Tag newTag = new Tag();
        newTag.Name = s;
        newTag.RefCount = 1;
        newTag.BlogEntries = new List<BlogEntry>(); // MODIFICATION
        newTag.BlogEntries.Add(newBlog); // MODIFICATION
        newBlog.BlogTags.Add(newTag);
        Db.Tags.Add(newTag);
    }
}
```

To see what blogs have the `html` tag, you just have to query on the `Tag` class and search through the `BlogEntries` to get the desired blogs. Good luck!